# WinRT c# load a sqlite database from folder asset

Tags: c#, database, sqlite, windows-8, windows-runtime

I would like to load a prefab sqlite database from the folder Assets at the launch and copy it in the localstate of the application.

I try a lot of thing and every time I have a "Access denied" or "file not found".

Have you any idea how to do it ?

Regards

Comment: Can you post some of your code?

Comment: Do you have it stored in a folder such as `Program Files` which requires Administration Rights and UAC Permission to invoke?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weird quirk for Win 8 RT.  I might guess that you have a special extension for your Sqlite db, like ".db" ... a workaround I have used is to use a ".txt" extension for the db in assets.

This works on my system without corrupting the file.  I checked the db in Sqlite Database Browser.

```
StorageFile file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromApplicationUriAsync(new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/db_in_assets.txt"));

await file.CopyAsync(ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder, "db_in_local.db");
```

Comment: that's work. I tried with extension "db" and that didn't work. Thanks a lot